# The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager ......... failed with error code 0x80004005

Tags: ssis

Setup:
SQL Server 2017
VS 2017
Oracle 12c

> [Oracle Destination [24]] Error : « The AcquireConnection method call
> to the connection manager ....... failed with error code 0x80004005.
> There may be error messages posted before this with more information
> on why the AcquireConnection method call failed.

Any idea about the above error message?

Answer (score 1):

Remove all the clients and install only one version of Oracle Client 32 or 64 bit client.

Comment: Thanks Amira, but why do we need the 64bit version when VS is only a 32-bit application?

Comment: It was a typo check your architecture and install 32 or 64

Comment: Your problem is with the data provider right ?